# How to launch uwp webview app in full screen mode by default

Tags: javascript, uwp, fullscreen

We have created a full fledged UWP webview app (WinJs) with help of Visual Studio 2017. Recently going through microsoft documentation and stackoverflow threads, we found out that the uwp app can be launched full screen with title bar removed.

Following code needed to inserted into App.Xaml.Cs file

```
ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

But the problem here is that, we are unable to locate this file to insert this. May be its because of WinJS template i have chosen, i don't know.

Other notables files include main.js | packageapp.manifest file.  I do not know whether this code could be integrated with either of this file.

Edit:
With roy's help, the main js file is modified according to the sample given in windows universal sample github, but still full screen does not seem to open up.

The main.js file code is as given below

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var isFirstActivation = true;

    var ViewManagement = Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    var ApplicationViewWindowingMode = ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode;
    var ApplicationView = ViewManagement.ApplicationView;

    
        
    function onLaunchInFullScreenModeChanged() {
        ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode = launchInFullScreenMode.checked ? ApplicationViewWindowingMode.fullScreen : ApplicationViewWindowingMode.auto;
    }

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand) {
            // TODO: Handle relevant ActivationKinds. For example, if your app can be started by voice commands,
            // this is a good place to decide whether to populate an input field or choose a different initial view.
        }
        else if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            launchInFullScreenMode.addEventListener("click", onLaunchInFullScreenModeChanged);

            launchInFullScreenMode.checked = ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode == ApplicationViewWindowingMode.fullScreen;
            // A Launch activation happens when the user launches your app via the tile
            // or invokes a toast notification by clicking or tapping on the body.
            if (args.detail.arguments) {
                // TODO: If the app supports toasts, use this value from the toast payload to determine where in the app
                // to take the user in response to them invoking a toast notification.
            }
            else if (args.detail.previousExecutionState === activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application had been suspended and was then terminated to reclaim memory.
                // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
                // Note: You may want to record the time when the app was last suspended and only restore state if they've returned after a short period.
            }
        }

        if (!args.detail.prelaunchActivated) {
            // TODO: If prelaunchActivated were true, it would mean the app was prelaunched in the background as an optimization.
            // In that case it would be suspended shortly thereafter.
            // Any long-running operations (like expensive network or disk I/O) or changes to user state which occur at launch
            // should be done here (to avoid doing them in the prelaunch case).
            // Alternatively, this work can be done in a resume or visibilitychanged handler.
        }

        if (isFirstActivation) {
            // TODO: The app was activated and had not been running. Do general startup initialization here.
            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged);
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll();
            launchInFullScreenMode.addEventListener("click", onLaunchInFullScreenModeChanged);
            launchInFullScreenMode.checked = ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode == ApplicationViewWindowingMode.fullScreen;
        }

        isFirstActivation = false;
    };

    function onVisibilityChanged(args) {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            // TODO: The app just became visible. This may be a good time to refresh the view.
        }
    }

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state that needs to persist across suspensions here.
        // You might use the WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically saved and restored across suspension.
        // If you need to complete an asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call args.setPromise().
    };

    app.start();

})();
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code in a JS file that will be referenced by the HTML that you are showing.

There used to be a JS UWP FullScreenMode Sample here: [FullScreenMode JS](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/archived/FullScreenMode). Although it is archived, you could still take a look at **scenario2-launch.js** and **scenario1-basic.js**. It shows how to these APIs are used in JavaScript.

Comment: Have you checked the sample I gave? The sample shows the whole process of how to use the fullscreen mode in the JS project.

Comment: What you need to do is to use these full screen mode API in the js file which is referenced by the html

Comment: Hi roy, i'm using scenario2.launch js code right now, since the app uses webview technology, i'm at loss at whether is there any need to use this particular line                                                                 
var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/scenario2-launch.html" in the code.

Comment: You don't need to copy the whole sample js file into your project. As I mentioned, you just need to add the code of the scenario2 into your JS file.